# "Exception: No extension found at None" when trying on use Selenium Firefox WebDriver on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Any ideas?

```
In [1]: from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

In [2]: d=WebDriver()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/selenium-read-only/<ipython console> in <module>()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.0_dev-py2.6.egg/selenium/firefox/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, profile, timeout)
     48             profile = FirefoxProfile(name=profile)
     49         if not profile:
---> 50             profile = FirefoxProfile()
     51         self.browser.launch_browser(profile)
     52         RemoteWebDriver.__init__(self,

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.0_dev-py2.6.egg/selenium/firefox/firefox_profile.pyc in __init__(self, name, port, template_profile, extension_path)
     72 
     73         if name == ANONYMOUS_PROFILE_NAME:
---> 74             self._create_anonymous_profile(template_profile)
     75             self._refresh_ini()
     76         else:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.0_dev-py2.6.egg/selenium/firefox/firefox_profile.pyc in _create_anonymous_profile(self, template_profile)
     82             self._copy_profile_source(template_profile)
     83         self._update_user_preference()
---> 84         self.add_extension(extension_zip_path=self.extension_path)
     85         self._launch_in_silent()
     86 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.0_dev-py2.6.egg/selenium/firefox/firefox_profile.pyc in add_extension(self, force_create, extension_zip_path)
    152                 not os.path.exists(extension_source_path)):
    153                 raise Exception(
--> 154                     "No extension found at %s" % extension_source_path)
    155 
    156             logging.debug("extension_source_path : %s" % extension_source_path)

Exception: No extension found at None
```

Comment: This is me seconding the question as I'm having the same issue. But I'm on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved it by discovering that the virtualenv was I installed via macports was "missing",

```
sudo ln -s `which virtualenv-2.6` /opt/local/bin/virtualenv
```

then running `rake firefox` and finally `rake firefox_xpi` ...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've gotten past this Exception by manually creating the `webdriver-extension.zip` file and copying it to the `selenium/firefox` folder in my site-packages directory.

Everything that follows assumes you have gotten a copy of the source code from http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ (using subversion/svn)

If you have Ruby installed you might be able to run `rake firefox` (that's Ruby make), which is the way you are supposed to build the zip file.  Since I don't have ruby installed, I just looked at the `/Rakefile` and figured out what was supposed to be in the zip.

Basically you just need to add everything in the `/firefox/src/extension/` folder.  On windows I added the `/firefox/prebuilt/Win32/Release/webdriver-firefox.dll` to it as well, but I'm not sure I needed to.  (On linux you may need to add the appropriate .so file).

Answer (score 0):

what is the following code doing?

```
from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
d = WebDriver()
```

a proper webdriver import and firefox instantiation looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Firefox()
```